# Laravel http facade conditionally add methods

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, facade

I'm working in Laravel 8 and am using the Http facade client to make requests. Currently, my set up has a database table where I store a `auth_type` enum column with the different auth types, I also have a `method` column stored as an enum.

With a Laravel model I know you can do `Model::query();` and append methods dynamically, but can this be done with the Http facade as my code is extremely long, covering an `if` statement for each method, and in each method is more `if` statements for the auth types and it seems like there could be a cleaner solution to my working code:

```php
if ($monitor->method == 'get') {
    if ($monitor->auth_type == 'basic') {
        return Http::withBasicAuth($monitor->username, $monitor->password)
                   ->withHeaders($headers)
                   ->timeout($timeout)
                   ->get($monitor->url);
    }
    if ($monitor->auth_type == 'digest') {
        return Http::withDigestAuth($monitor->username, $monitor->password)
                   ->withHeaders($headers)
                   ->timeout($timeout)
                   ->get($monitor->url);
    }
    if ($monitor->auth_type == 'token') {
        return Http::withToken($monitor->password)
                   ->withHeaders($headers)
                   ->timeout($timeout)
                   ->get($monitor->url);
    }

    return Http::withHeaders($headers)
               ->timeout($timeout)
               ->get($monitor->url);
}
```

Comment: I understand how a switch works, except in my description I only included 4 return statements since I didn't want to bloat the description. In reality, I have every method: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH and HEAD. Meaning, a lot more statements, so a switch wouldn't really solve the issue here.

Comment: The version below with `match` is still the least redundant code - also uses instance instead of scope resolution operator.

Comment: @RyanH, so you asked for something like `Model::query()` and you've got it. but if you're trying to over-engineering your code, that's another question, since you've got so many statements. in other hand you can achieve handling these statements with a quick refactor to SOLID.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried something like this?

Edit 01: there's no need to return in if statements, since I've forgot to remove them when i was copying them in other statements.

```
$http = Http::withHeaders([
    'content-type'  =>  'application-json',
    'accept'  =>  'application-json',
]);
return $http->withBasicAuth('likeUser', 'password')
    ->timeout(3000)
    ->get('google.com');
```

I've done something like this and worked, and now base on what you've asked, you can do something like below :

```
if ($monitor->method == 'get') {
    $http = Http::withHeaders($headers)
        ->timeout($timeout);
    if ($monitor->auth_type == 'basic') {
        $http->withBasicAuth($monitor->username, $monitor->password);
    }
    if ($monitor->auth_type == 'digest') {
        $http->withDigestAuth($monitor->username, $monitor->password);
    }
    if ($monitor->auth_type == 'token') {
        $http->withToken($monitor->password);
    }
    return $http->get($monitor->url);
}
```

Or using Switch Statement:

```
if ($monitor->method == 'get') {
    $http = Http::withHeaders($headers)
        ->timeout($timeout);
    switch ($monitor->auth_type) {
        case 'basic':
            $http->withBasicAuth($monitor->username, $monitor->password);
            break;
        case 'digest':
            $http->withDigestAuth($monitor->username, $monitor->password);
            break;
        case 'token':
            $http->withToken($monitor->password);
            break;
    }
    return $http->get($monitor->url);
}
```

And ofc match in PHP 8, my favorite:

```
if ($monitor->method == 'get') {
    $http = Http::withHeaders($headers)
        ->timeout($timeout);
    match ($monitor->auth_type) {
        'basic' => $http->withBasicAuth($monitor->username, $monitor->password),
        'digest' => $http->withDigestAuth($monitor->username, $monitor->password),
        'token' => $http->withToken($monitor->password),
    };
    return $http->get($monitor->url);
}
```

In case, you're curios about [match in PHP 8](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php)...

Answer (score 0):

[`Http`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Http.php) uses [`Illuminate\Http\Client\Factory`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/Factory.php) & `Illuminate\Http\Client\PendingRequest`.

While [Guzzle](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/index.html) would actually take the HTTP verb as first argument:

```
// just for example.
$options = [
    RequestOptions::HEADERS => $headers,
    RequestOptions::JSON => $post_fields
];

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
return $client->request(strtoupper($monitor->method), $monitor->url, $options);
```

Maybe store the string as uppercase?!